# Add New Row Datatables JQuery: Requested unknown parameter 'PainSite' for row 2, column 1

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I am trying to add a new row in this datatable using row.add(). But then I get this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=tblPainAssessChart - Requested unknown parameter 'PainSite' for row 2, column 1.

Here's the datatable initialization:

```
      gblPainChartTable = $('#tblPainAssessChart').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            language: { search: "",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search",
                sLengthMenu: "_MENU_items"

            },
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('getAjaxPainAssessChartData', ['id' =>  $T_Patient->id]) !!}',
            columns: [
                {
                    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        data = moment(row.Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
                       return data;
                    }
                },
                { data: 'PainSite', name:'PainSite'},
                { data: 'TypeofPain', name: 'TypeofPain'},
                { data: 'PainDegree', name: 'PainDegree'},
                {
                    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                       
                        data = ''
                        // + '<a onclick="editPA(' + meta.row + ')" class="blue-text btn-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-stop action-icon-img"></i></a>'
                        // + '<a onclick="removePA(' + meta.row + ')" class="red-text btn-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times action-icon-img"></i></a>'
                        // +'';
                        
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": 0, // Date
                    "className": "text-center"
                },
                {
                    "targets": 1, // PainSites
                    "className": "text-center",
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": 2, // Type of Pain
                    "className": "text-center",
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": 3, // PainDegree
                    "className": "text-center",
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": 4, // Action 
                    "className": "text-center",
                    "orderable": false
                },
            ]
        });
```

And this is the function to add a new row to the datatable.

```
function addPA(){

     var DatePA = $("#Date").val();
     var PainSite = $("#PainSite").val();
     var TypeofPain = $("#TypeofPain").val();
     var PainDegree = $("#PainDegree").val();
     var DatePAF = moment(DatePA).format("DD-MMM-YYYY"); 
           
      gblPainChartTable.row.add( [
            DatePAF, 
            PainSite,
            TypeofPain,
            PainDegree, 
           '<a onclick="editPA(' + lastPANo + ')" class="blue-text btn-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt action-icon-img"></i></a>' +
           '<a onclick="removePA(' + lastPANo + ')" class="red-text btn-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash action-icon-img"></i></a>'

       ]).draw();
}
```

What am i missing?

EDIT :

It's not showing the error now, but it still doesn't add the new row to the table

Answer (score 0):

You are using ajax, so if you have this columns defined in `columns`:

```
{
    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        data = moment(row.Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
       return data;
    }
},
{ data: 'PainSite', name:'PainSite'},
{ data: 'TypeofPain', name: 'TypeofPain'},
{ data: 'PainDegree', name: 'PainDegree'},
{
    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
       
        data = ''
        // + '<a onclick="editPA(' + meta.row + ')" class="blue-text btn-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-stop action-icon-img"></i></a>'
        // + '<a onclick="removePA(' + meta.row + ')" class="red-text btn-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times action-icon-img"></i></a>'
        // +'';
        
        return data;
    }
}
```

**You have to pass in add or update method an object with same fields you use in `columns`**, like this:

```
gblPainChartTable.rows.add([{
    "Date": DateValue,
    "PainSite": PainSiteValue,
    "TypeofPain": TypeofPainValue,
    "PainDegree": PainDegreeValue
}]).draw()
```

**EDIT 1**:

Then you can order the table with the new row if you want.
By default, **row is added at last position (I think)** and, If you want in other position, you have to do something similar to:

```
gblPainChartTable.order([0, 'asc'], [3, "asc"]).draw()
```

**EDIT 2**:

See [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43197/row-add-not-working-ajax-server-side), with `serverSide`...:

> If you want to add a new row, you have to add it at the data source
> (in the case of server-side processing, that is at the server-side -
> typically a database table)

Code above is for tables without `serverSide`, but I see that you have it.

The solition is add data to database (or ajax source) and then something similar to:

```
gblPainChartTable.clear();
gblPainChartTable.draw();
gblPainChartTable.ajax.reload();
```

One more thing... Are you sure that you want use [serverSide](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)?

Comment: I have changed it to what you showed, it doesn't show the error anymore, but it still doesn't add the new row to the datatable

Comment: @littlebean Edited, I think that row is added in last position...

Comment: I don't think it is added to the table. Cause when I inspect it, there are only the original 2 rows in the table, no new rows added. I've tried readjusting the position like you said, the new row is not there.

Comment: Um...So, the way I want it to work is, I have an add button which will call the addPA() function like I've shown above and add a new row to the datatable, (I dont want it to be saved to the database table yet), in the row, there will also be an edit button to edit that row. After clicking on a save button at the bottom of the page only it will post the data to the database.

Comment: Currently, that save button I am using ajax to post the values server-side. Then draw() and update the datatable. So I guess i need server-side for this? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know all the data that you need but... Try using server side and not use row add, use ajax reload instead after updating database and tell me